# iPad stuck on restoring media for a whole year

Tags: ipad, icloud, backup, restore

I got an iPad Air 2 a year ago and since then it has not finished the iCloud restore it started a year ago.

It has been on for at least a month of that year if not much more of the year. 
It has been on WiFi with 12 MBPS download speed and 1.5 MBPS upload speed.
When I go into settings the only thing it says is "Restoring media" so I guess it must be stuck on a video or something.

I thought I could start over again but it says that the data will not be backed up or restored in the future if I stop the restore so all that would do is delete the data from iCloud forever.

If I did click stop could I then do another backup from my phone and then restore that backup to the iPad?

So the only thing to do is wait.

But I've been waiting for a whole year now...

I need to upgrade to iOS 13 so I can test Swift UI apps which I have developed but I cannot do that until the restore has completed (or been stopped without data loss).

Would simply signing out of my Apple ID stop the restore and keep the data or would you lose the data if you did that?

Comment: https://www.imyfone.com/backup-restore-iphone/iphone-getting-stuck-on-restoring-media/ - did you try the solution 2 mentioned on this link